# MMC, Active Directory Users and Computers, why is properties missing most tabs?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, windows-10, mmc

This question has been asked several times on other forums, but most answers I've found are for Windows 7, Windows Vista, or don't apply to my situation at all.

My issue is that when I go to the `Properties` section of any object in Active Directory, I get only 5 tabs, shown below:

[image]

The most common solution for this seems to be installing Remote Server Administrative Tools.  Which I have done, and it is the newest version.

After that, the most common problem seems to be that you have to enable the AD services in Programs and Features, which is done, and shown below:

[image]

I have also already enabled the Advanced features.  Which adds tabs, but not the missing ones.  Just extra ones I don't need.

After this step, I've seen lots of answers for Windows 7 and Vista (It may also apply to 10, I'm not sure), where they copied files name `tsuserex.dll` and `tsuserex.dll.mui` from their server, to their local computer.  I haven't done this yet, because it seems pretty weird to me.  I'm a junior/mid level person in the IT world, but moving around dll's to get some tabs to appear seems odd to me.  If that really is the next step I'll do it, but can someone explain to me why I'd need to do that, if that's the case?

I'm more than happy to try anything else though.

---

**Extra Info.**

- The AD server is Windows Server 2012 Standard
- I have also gone through the steps shown [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725609.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  Which is basically just making sure the Remote Desktop Services - Extensions has the correct checkboxes checked.  And it was all as it should be.
- To be thorough, the RSAT I downloaded was **KB2693643**
- I have also uninstalled and re-installed the server tools.

Comment: I'm actually still having this problem.  Only on this computer.  I have been remoting into another computer to do anything I need to in a management console that isn't broken.  I still haven't tried to just reinstall windows, but eventually I may have to.

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to enable "Advanced Features".

[image: ADUC - View - Advanced Features]

Comment: Sorry, I meant to put that in the original question.  Advanced features does not contain the missing tabs.  It's some other one's that I don't need.  I'll add that to the question now.  I'm going to upvote the answer though because I'm sure someone will find this that needs it.